# discordjs using base64 image in webhook embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do I insert an image into a discord embed using webhook.
I have the image saved as a base64 string which I get from database. I have tried this but
I only get an empty embed

[image: discord]

```js
const data = b64image.split(',')[1]; 
const buf = new Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
const file = new Discord.MessageAttachment(buf, 'img.jpeg');

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setImage('attachment://img.jpeg')

webhookClient.send('', {
    username: userName,
    embeds: [embed],
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with a smaller image, and the code in the question worked. So it was a problem with the size of the request.
I fixed it by setting up an express route to serve images and used the URL in the embed

```js
router.get('/thumb/:imgId', (req, res) => {
    const imgId = req.params.imgId.toString().trim();
    let file = Buffer.from(b64Image.split(',')[1], 'base64')
    res.status(200);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    res.set('Content-Length', file.length)
    res.send(file)
});
```

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setImage(`${base_url}/img/thumb/${imgId}`)
    
webhookClient.send('', {
    username: userName,
    embeds: [embed],
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Enter the code here. Discord has added a feature (or it was already there, I don't know), which enables you to do what you want to do.

```js
const data = b64image.split(',')[1]; 
const buf = new Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
const file = new Discord.MessageAttachment(buf, 'img.jpeg');

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .attachFiles(file)
    .setImage('attachment://img.jpeg')

webhookClient.send('', {
    username: userName,
    embeds: [embed],
});
```